# How does the Proportional fill Algorithm in SQL 2005/2008 work?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql, tempdb

When we setup multiple data files for tempdb I understand SQL Server uses a Proportional Fill algorithm. How does it work? Does it use the same method for user databases aswell.

I have tried to understand it using the SQL Internals Viewer but was unable to get consistent results and hence am a bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does use the same fill mechanism as user databases. It basically uses a proportional "round robin" format. You can read the BOL version of how it works here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187087.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Scott, I'll verify the explaination on the link for tempdb tomorrow and feedback.

Comment: I tested the theory with same sized tempdb data files. It is all good with Same size files though there is still a minor point as to whether the proportional fill is based on available free space or the actual data file size. Rest all tallys with the explaination.